# D3 zoom is not properly reseting zoom state and translated location

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, zooming, scale

Well I already got it working, but somehow when tested now it does not work anymore. So in my project I have a **map** that is **zoom**- and **dragable**. When zoomed in or dragged you can always click a **Reset button** to reset the whole presention. That works great.

So the **zoom definition**:

```
var g = svg.append("g");
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate([0, 0])
    .scale(1)
    .scaleExtent([1, maximumZoom])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);
svg.call(zoom);
```

and the **zoom function** is:

```
g.attr("transform", "translate([0,0]).scale(" + 1 + ")");
zoom.translate([0, 0]);
zoom.scale(1);
```

The reset is done properly when the Reset button is clicked. But when now zooming or dragging anywhere, you actually see that it was the old zoom and location.

But the strange thing is that :

```
zoom.translate([0, 0]);
zoom.scale(1);
```

should fix that issue. As I said 1 month ago it worked properly.

In addition also the zoomed function:

```
function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it seems that **calling** the **zoom event** or let's say setting the zoom event **later** on on the svg element is fixing that issue.

So simply call

```
zoom.on("zoom", zoomed);
svg.call(zoom);
```

after everything is finished. I put it into a function that is loading the map. And now it's again working properly.

You can see the website [**here**](http://arda-maps.org/).